# extracting images from a folder based on a text file

Tags: batch-file

my website (based on zencart system) is quite large, and I have a backup of all csv and image files on my computer

as I have over 100,000 products (yes I do know how slow zencart can be on a slow server) and my intention is to filter the list onto separate website so that each site carries a different category

my problem comes when I upload the csv product files, and the images, some of the images seem to be missing, but to go through 100,000 product lines would be a nightmare.

I had a good excel programmer friend help me out one time, with the following batch file, which was of enormous help, and probably will be for anyone else wanting to filter out images from a huge folder, based on those inside a text file

is there anyone who can take this a step further, and have the batch file dump a list of the filenames it was **not** able to find, into a separate file?

batch.bat file is

```
 @echo off & setlocal
 :: assuming this is where they are, if not, adjust as needed:
 set location=C:\Users\Windows7\Desktop\iwantafiles\fullcsvfiles\categories\mobiles\i mages
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%location%\imagelist.txt) do (
 copy "%location%\%%a" c:\imagelist
 )
 ::end batchscript
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of

```
copy "%location%\%%a" c:\imagelist
```

put

```
if not exist "%location%\%%a" >>missinglist.txt echo %%a
```

and you could put the `%%a` in the `ECHO` clause between "rabbit's ears" if that suits your purpose.

Comment: if not exist "%location%\%%a" >>missinglist.txt echo "%%a"

Comment: with the "" it seems to produce a short list. Checking to see if these have images against them, but it loos like it works, THANK YOU